# Xfce - is there any way to speed up "close window" for unresponsive applications?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, process, kill

In Xubuntu 20.04, if a window won't close first time, it brings up a dialogue with words to the effect of "This application is taking a long time to close, do you want to kill the process?"

What is it actually doing? Is it something like sending 5 close requests with a 5s interval between them and if the process is still running it then offers the user to send a kill request?

Can the number of attempts or the interval be changed somewhere as a setting? Or is there any way to add "kill" to the right mouse menu?

Comment: Is this something you need to do a lot? Close windows for apps that have crashed?

Comment: yes - this would be useful a few times a day. I miss the immediacy of right-click>kill window in Joe's Window Manager

Comment: I would be more concerned WHY the processes are crashing then closing them more quickly.

Comment: having been using Ubuntu since v4 I would put it down to volunteer/hobbyist programmers drifting away and losing interest before sufficient debugging is done. The main culprits on my system are the commercial programs Firefox and the Nvidia driver, but these are a macro/corporate-scale version of the same problem. The workround is to be able to close processes quickly and decisively - and even this is messy for the user. The 'x' to close window behaviour in Xfce often doesn't close the window. I've tried the ctrl+alt+esc shortcut once today, but it isn't explained well and (once) didn't work

Answer (score 1):

## **Warning**

According to `man xkill`

> Xkill is a utility for forcing the X server  to  close  connections
> to clients. **This program  is very dangerous, but is useful for
> aborting programs that have displayed undesired windows on a user's
> screen.**   If no  resource identifier is given with -id, xkill will
> display a special cursor as a prompt for the user to select a window
> to be killed.  If  a pointer button is pressed over a non-root window,
> the server will close its connection to the client that created the
> window.

I've tested in Xubuntu 20.04.3 and in *Setting / Keyboard / Application Shortcuts*, there is a default shortcut to xkill. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>.

A "X" sign will appear on your screen. If you don't want to kill any Window/Software, right click. If you want to kill a process, it's a left click on the window or software's window. If you're working on important stuff in your session, you should not use `xkill` or with precautions. I use it sometimes and it is fast and work well. Sometimes I like to live dangerously. Use at your own risk.

You can also open the **Task Manager** and Stop, Terminate or Kill a process.

Source for the following : [Difference between stop, kill and terminate in Xfce task manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/difference-between-stop-kill-and-terminate-in-xfce-task-manager-1-0-1)

From user **Aloha** on unix.stackexchange.

> It sends different stop signals to a process. Here's some info:
>
> - Stop: *SIGSTOP* - This signal makes the operating system **pause** a process's execution. The process **cannot ignore** the signal.
> - Kill: *SIGKILL* - The SIGKILL signal forces the process to **stop executing immediately**. The program **cannot ignore** this signal.
>   This process does not get to clean-up either.
> - Terminate: *SIGTERM* - *This signal requests a process to stop running.* **This signal can be ignored.** The process is given time to
>   gracefully shutdown. When a program gracefully shuts down, that means
>   it is given time to save its progress and release resources. In other
>   words, it is not forced to stop. SIGINT is very similar to SIGTERM.